# How to hash an entire table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, hash

I'd like to get a hash for data in an entire table. I need to compare two databases after migration to validate that the data migration was successful. Is it possible to reliably and reproducibly generate a hash for an entire table in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from the command line (replacing of course `my_database` and `my_table`):

```
psql my_database -c 'copy my_table to stdout' |sha1sum
```

If you want to use a query to limit columns, add ordering, etc., just modify the query:

```
psql my_database -c 'copy (select * from my_table order by my_id_column) to stdout' |sha1sum
```

Note that this does not hash anything except the column **data**. No schema information, constraints, indexes, metadata, permissions, etc.

Note also that `sha1sum` is an arbitrary hashing program; you can pipe this to any program that generates a hash. Some [cuspy](http://catb.org/jargon/html/C/cuspy.html) options are `sha256sum` and `md5sum`.

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY`, and I for one will upvote.